# MS Word VBA freeze when accessing document object

Tags: vba, ms-word, vb6

I've come across a very strange situation with MS Word VBA in VB6.  I have not tried using .NET. I am using Office 2016, but this behavior also occurs in previous versions (2013 for sure). I am using the MSWORD.OLB reference in my project. This behavior only occurs when you associate another program with .RTF files in the windows default programs (i.e. set default app for RTF files to WordPad in the "Default programs" control panel).  After doing this, if you try to execute this simple code below, you will get a "Application is busy" error dialog. After cancelling a few times, you eventually get a "Call was rejected by Callee" error. Runtime Error "-2147418111 (80010001)". This seems to occur any time you attempt to access the wordDoc reference. Has anyone encountered this and found a fix?

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    wordDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason you use `CreateObject("Word.Application")` instead of `New Word.Application`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't change the result. The busy message still occurs.